# FET with high current ( power JFET) low VGSoff

Tags: jfet, fet

I am looking for a N- channel JFET part number with IDmax > = 800 mA  and low VGS(off) < -15 volts. I dont focus on the frequency As an inherent charactristics of JFETs is high working frequency but I need a good working maximum frequency of 100 MHz or above. 
I googled for that but Low vgs( off) jFETs  are rare. The main reason I need such low vgs is its usage as a source follower with a " Large Signal" for current gain
Anyone knows a part number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you can find such a JFET. IMO your best bet is JFET - Bipolar combo.
Take a look at this ancient National app note.
http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa620/snoa620.pdf

Hope this helps.